# SK Rapid U041600 + C10A301 + U140600 - link beween trouble codes

Tags: obd-ii, cel, skoda, vacuum

Škoda Rapid (2019) 1.0 TSI shows these three trouble codes on OBD diagnostics. Check engine light is glowing, start-stop shows an error, engine performance seems unchanged.
Internet search suggests engine error is caused by the faulty vacuum sensor.

```
01 Engine: U041600 - Invalid Data Received From Vehicle Dynamics Control Module
            Intermittent
03 Brakes: C10A301 - Vacuum sensor Electrical error
19 Gateway: U140600 - Static current too high
```

How could this be connected to the `Static current too high`? All three errors firstly appeared when dashcam was left forgotten on in the car. Could that have triggered the problems? What would the mechanism be? How are these three linked together?